# How to return variables to multiple methods at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to return multiple variables to a method as:

```
def groupby(self, df, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate):
    datamin = df.loc[df.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmin()]
    datamax = df.loc[df.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmax()]
    return plotsview.weatherplot(self, datamin, datamax)
```

Is it possible to return same `datmin, datamax` to another method at a time?

as:

```
return plotsview.newplot(self, datamin, datamax)
```

I am returning them to the below methods:

```
class plotsview:
    def weatherplot(self, datamax1, datamin1):
```

and

```
class plotsviewnew:
    def newplot(self, datamax, datamin):
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean... Do you want to return from your function `groupby` both the result of `weatherplot` and the result of `newplot`?

Comment: to return the `datamin` and `datamax` to two methods at once

Comment: when you say `return` do you mean *pass as arguments*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return 2 values you can return a tuple. Just calculate your values into variables and then return them:

```py
def groupby(self, df, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate):
    datamin = df.loc[df.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmin()]
    datamax = df.loc[df.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmax()]

    weather_res = plotsview.weatherplot(self,datamin,datamax)
    new_res = plotsview.newplot(self,datamin,datamax)

    return weather_res, new_res
```

Comment: Here I am passing datamin,datamax to other methods as parameters so returning the above way works?

Comment: I have edited my question , and I want to access these returned values as params for mentioned methods

Comment: If your question is simply if you can pass these same 2 variables to 2 methods the answer is yes, you can pass any variable to as many functions as you want. If your question is about returning multiple values, then the code above does that

Comment: yes I understood completely, what if there are multiple values ?  for eg: i don't know exactly how many variables I am passing(returning) to a method, how to write that method to access all passed variables? (using *args??)

Comment: In more detailed way, i am returning a,b,c,d,e to a method say def foo():   , now how can I access all values or any number of those values based on requirement in foo()?

Comment: I am having a really hard time understanding. I think you are misusing return/pass/access. `return` is the value that a function returns and can then be used. for example `x = max(1, 2)` 2 is the return value of `max`. We are passing arguments to functions. In the above example, 1 and 2 are arguments being passed to `max`

Comment: With that said, if you have an unknown number of arguments to a function, the answer is yes, use `*args`. `def foo(*args)` and then inside `foo` you can do for example `for arg in args` and loop through all given arguments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199306/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-tomerikoo).